# Getting my banner slideshow to replay after it has run through

Tags: javascript

my slideshow is running through once and not restarting once it has run through. I have posted all the code I have below.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.banner1').show();
        $('div.banner1').show();
        $('.nav ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('child3');
        $('.nav ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass('child4');
        promoCycle = setInterval('cycle()', 5000);
    });

    $('a.banner2').mouseover(function() {
    $('.banner img.banner2').show();
    $('.banner .texts div.banner2').show();
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
$('a.banner3').mouseover(function() {
    $('.banner img.banner3').show();
    $('.banner .texts div.banner3').show();
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
$('a.banner4').mouseover(function() {
    $('.banner img.banner4').show();
    $('.banner .texts div.banner4').show();
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
$('a.banner5').mouseover(function() {
    $('.banner img.banner5').show();
    $('.banner .texts div.banner5').show();
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner2').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner2').hide();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
$('.banner .buttons').mouseout(function() {
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    $('.banner img.banner1').show();
    $('.banner .texts div.banner1').show();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
var count = 1;
function cycle(){
    count++;
    if (count == 2) {
        $('.banner .buttons li.banner2').addClass('on');
        $('.banner img.banner2').show();
        $('.banner .texts div.banner2').show();
        $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
        $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
        $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    }
    if (count == 3) {
        $('.banner .buttons li.banner3').addClass('on');
        $('.banner img.banner3').show();
        $('.banner .texts div.banner3').show();
        $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
        $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
        $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    }
    if (count == 4) {
        $('.banner .buttons li.banner4').addClass('on');
        $('.banner img.banner4').show();
        $('.banner .texts div.banner4').show();
        $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
        $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
        $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner5').hide();
    }
    if (count == 5) {
        $('.banner .buttons li.banner5').addClass('on');
        $('.banner img.banner5').show();
        $('.banner .texts div.banner5').show();
        $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner1,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner2').removeClass('on');
        $('.banner .texts div.banner1,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner2').hide();
        $('.banner img.banner1,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner2').hide();
    }
    if (count == 6) {
        $('.banner img.banner1').show();
        $('.banner .texts div.banner1').show();
        $('.banner .buttons ul li.banner2,.banner .buttons ul li.banner3,.banner .buttons ul li.banner4,.banner .buttons ul li.banner5').removeClass('on');
        $('.banner .texts div.banner2,.banner .texts div.banner3,.banner .texts div.banner4,.banner .texts div.banner5').hide();
        $('.banner img.banner2,.banner img.banner3,.banner img.banner4,.banner img.banner5').hide();
        clearInterval(promoCycle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is your are using `clearInterval` after the last banner.  This stops the cycle from repeating.  Instead, you should reset `count` to `1` and remove the call to `clearInterval`.

Also, it looks like your `mouseout` code is trying to resume the cycle.  Instead of `clearInterval`, you should again use `promoCycle = setInterval(cycle, 5000)`.

All that being said... *Holy code-bloat batman!*  You can pare down that code dramatically!  Here's a shot I took at it (untested, since I don't have your html):

```
var promoCycle = 0;
$(function ()
{
    $('img.banner1, div.banner1').show();
    $('.nav ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('child3');
    $('.nav ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass('child4');
    promoCycle = setInterval(showBanner, 5000);
    $('a.banner1').mouseover(bannerHover(1));
    $('a.banner2').mouseover(bannerHover(2));
    $('a.banner3').mouseover(bannerHover(3));
    $('a.banner4').mouseover(bannerHover(4));
    $('a.banner5').mouseover(bannerHover(5));
    $('.banner .buttons').mouseout(function ()
    {
        promoCycle = setInterval(showBanner, 5000);
    });
});
function bannerHover(i)
{
    return function ()
    {
        bannerIndex = i;
        showBanner();
        clearInterval(promoCycle);
    };
}
var bannerIndex = 0
function showBanner()
{
    var index = (bannerIndex++ % 5) + 1;
    $('.banner .texts div[class*=banner],banner img[class*=banner]').hide();
    $('.banner .buttons ul li.on[class*=banner]').removeClass('on');
    $('.banner .buttons li.banner' + index).addClass('on');
    $('.banner img.banner'+index+',.banner .texts div.banner'+index).show();
}
```

I would actually go further and replace `class="banner1"` with `<div banner="1">` (for all bannerX elements, not just divs).  This way you can use jQuery selectors like:

```
$(".banner div[banner=1]");
$("a[banner]");
$(this).attr("banner");
```

For example, binding `$("a.bannerX").mouseover` would be simplified from 5 calls to just one with no need for a function constructor:

```
$("a[banner]").mouseover(function()
{
    bannerIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("banner"));
    showBanner();
    clearInterval(promoCycle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the count after your last banner. Every time `cycle()` runs, it's incrementing the `count` variable by one. After it shows the last banner, it keeps incrementing (7, 8, etc.), which doesn't satisfy any of your conditions.

```
if (count == 6 {
    ... your code ...
   count = 1;
}
```

I'd look into refactoring your code, too, since you repeat yourself a lot.